# Was Moses' original scroll used as a blueprint for all following scrolls?

Tags: sefer-torah, vayelech

In Parashat Vayelech, Moses writes/completes a Torah scroll and hands it over to Kohanim to keep it in the Holy Ark.

Does anybody mention that its purpose was to serve as a blueprint for other Torah scrolls?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95555/13438), Ralbag explains that the point of this Torah was to prevent mistakes from creeping in to future Torah scrolls.

Comment: I +1 you in the linked answer. THank you. Anybody else?